# I need help getting an intent to open another activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I need to be able to touch a TextView and have it open up another page, however, when I run the app and touch the TextView the app crashes.

Here's the code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding= "10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.practiceapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numbers"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/numbers"
        android:text="@string/category_numbers"
        android:onClick="openNumbersList"/>
```

Here's the java code:

```
    package com.example.android.practiceapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void openNumbersList(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Numbers.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you added `Numbers` activity to the **manifest**? odds on the issue will be with the  Numbers activity. It would be helpful if you posted the log.

Comment: *the app crashes* is not a useful problem description. Where is the log? What does the stack trace tell you about what error occurred? See [ask]. This site is for *specific questions*, and *the app crashes. What's wrong?* is by no means *specific*.

Comment: Please provide the logcat output

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Numbers activity exists and is in your Android.manifest.

> All activities must be represented by  elements in the manifest file. Any that are not declared there will not be seen by the system and will never be run.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are not initialized your `TextView`

```
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.numbers)
```

Second, as others suggested, add **Numbers** activity in your `Android.manifest`

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the  clickable attribute, without it, the click handler isn't called. So, add it...

```
...

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/numbers"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/numbers"
        android:text="@string/category_numbers"
        android:onClick="openNumbersList"
        android:clickable="true"/>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the responses, i actually ran the debugger and it turns out i had to change my java code in the numbers file from "extends AppCompatActivity" to "extends Activity" like the MainActivity java file

Answer (score -1):

Try inserting

```
MainActivity.this
```

instead of

```
this
```

like so

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Numbers.class);
```

Comment: I believe that wouldn't fix anything; it's not like `new Intent()` is instantiated in an inner class.